# Spring Autowire error expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I am trying to Autowire beans in this project but keep getting error

> expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)"

Java:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/Home")
public class HomeController {

@Autowired
private Personrepo personRepo;

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(ModelMap model){
    List<Person> persons = personRepo.getAll();
    model.addAttribute("persons", persons);
    Person person = new Person();
    model.addAttribute("person", person);
    return "home";
}


@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView add(@ModelAttribute(value="person") Person person,BindingResult result){

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("home");
    if(!result.hasErrors()){
        personRepo.add(person);
        person = new Person();
        mv.addObject("person", person);
    }
    mv.addObject("persons", personRepo.getAll());
    return mv;
}


@RequestMapping(value="/edit", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView edit(@ModelAttribute(value="person") Person person,BindingResult result){

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("home");
    if(!result.hasErrors()){
        personRepo.edit(person);
        person = new Person();

        mv.addObject("person", person);
    }
    mv.addObject("persons", personRepo.getAll());
    return mv;
}
@RequestMapping(value="/delete", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute(value="person") Person person,BindingResult result){
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("home");
    if(!result.hasErrors()){
    personRepo.delete(person.getId());

        //personRepo.delete(person);
        person = new Person();

        mv.addObject("person", person);
    }
    mv.addObject("persons", personRepo.getAll());
    return mv;
}


}
```

Person

```
package com.app.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
* A simple POJO representing a Person
*/
 public class Person implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5527566248002296042L;

private String id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Double money;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Double getMoney() {
    return money;
}

public void setMoney(Double money) {
    this.money = money;
}

}
```

PersonRepo

```
package com.app.r;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.app.service.PersonService;
import com.app.domain.Person;


public interface Personrepo {

public void add(Person person);
public void edit(Person person);
public void delete(String id);
public List<Person> getAll();
}
```

PersonService

```
 package com.app.service;

 import java.sql.ResultSet;  
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import com.app.domain.Person;


import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;



@Component
@Transactional
public class PersonService {

protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("service");

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Resource(name="dataSource")
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

/**
 * Retrieves all persons
 * 
 * @return a list of persons
 */
public List<Person> getAll() {
    logger.debug("Retrieving all persons");

    // Prepare our SQL statement
    String sql = "select id, first_name, last_name, money from person";

    // Maps a SQL result to a Java object
    RowMapper<Person> mapper = new RowMapper<Person>() {  
        public Person mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setId(rs.getString("id"));
            person.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
            person.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));
            person.setMoney(rs.getDouble("money"));
            return person;
        }
    };

    // Retrieve all
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, mapper);
}

/**
 * Adds a new person
 * 
 * @param firstName the first name of the person
 * @param lastName the last name of the person
 * @param money the money of the person
 */
public void add(String firstName, String lastName, Double money) {
    logger.debug("Adding new person");

    // Prepare our SQL statement using Named Parameters style
    String sql = "insert into person(first_name, last_name, money) values " +
            "(:firstName, :lastName, :money)";

    // Assign values to parameters
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("firstName", firstName);
    parameters.put("lastName", lastName);
    parameters.put("money", money);

    // Save
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);
}





/**
 * Deletes an existing person
 * @param id the id of the existing person
 */
public void delete(String id) {
    logger.debug("Deleting existing person");

    // Prepare our SQL statement using Unnamed Parameters style
    String sql = "delete from person where id = ?";

    // Assign values to parameters
    Object[] parameters = new Object[] {id};

    // Delete
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);
}

/**
 * Edits an existing person
 * @param id the id of the existing person
 * @param firstName the first name of the existing person
 * @param lastName the last name of the existing person
 * @param money the money of the existing person
 */
public void edit(String id, String firstName, String lastName, Double money) {
    logger.debug("Editing existing person");

    // Prepare our SQL statement
    String sql = "update person set first_name = :firstName, " +
            "last_name = :lastName, money = :money where id = :id";

    // Assign values to parameters
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("id", id);
    parameters.put("firstName", firstName);
    parameters.put("lastName", lastName);
    parameters.put("money", money);

    // Edit
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);

}
 }
```

Servlet-context.xml

```
               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">




<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->





<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />


<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-     INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
<context:annotation-config />




<!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
 For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package-->





</beans:beans>
```

Web.xml

```
                   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-  app_2_5.xsd">



<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->


<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Error Console

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'servlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'servlet-servlet': startup date [Wed May 08 15:59:09 BST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@426b51d8: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,homeController,personService,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/Home/add],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.app.a.HomeController.add(com.app.domain.Person,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/Home/delete],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.app.a.HomeController.update(com.app.domain.Person,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/Home],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.app.a.HomeController.showForm(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/Home/edit],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.app.a.HomeController.edit(com.app.domain.Person,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@426b51d8: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,homeController,personService,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.app.r.Personrepo com.app.a.HomeController.personRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.app.r.Personrepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.app.r.Personrepo com.app.a.HomeController.personRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.app.r.Personrepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.app.r.Personrepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 32 more
May 8, 2013 3:59:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.app.r.Personrepo com.app.a.HomeController.personRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.app.r.Personrepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

PersonService Class update with implementation

```
package com.app.service;

@Component
public class PersonService implements Personrepo {

protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("service");

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Resource(name="dataSource")
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

/**
 * Retrieves all persons
 * 
 * @return a list of persons
 */
public List<Person> getAll() {
    logger.debug("Retrieving all persons");



    // Prepare our SQL statement
    String sql = "select id, first_name, last_name, money from person";



    // Maps a SQL result to a Java object
    RowMapper<Person> mapper = new RowMapper<Person>() {  
        public Person mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setId(rs.getString("id"));
            person.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
            person.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));
            person.setMoney(rs.getDouble("money"));
            return person;
        }
    };

    // Retrieve all
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, mapper);
}

/**
 * Adds a new person
 * 
 * @param firstName the first name of the person
 * @param lastName the last name of the person
 * @param money the money of the person
 */
public void add(String firstName, String lastName, Double money) {
    logger.debug("Adding new person");

    // Prepare our SQL statement using Named Parameters style
    String sql = "insert into person(first_name, last_name, money) values " +
            "(:firstName, :lastName, :money)";

    // Assign values to parameters
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("firstName", firstName);
    parameters.put("lastName", lastName);
    parameters.put("money", money);

    // Save
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);
}





/**
 * Deletes an existing person
 * @param id the id of the existing person
 */
public void delete(String id) {
    logger.debug("Deleting existing person");

    // Prepare our SQL statement using Unnamed Parameters style
    String sql = "delete from person where id = ?";

    // Assign values to parameters
    Object[] parameters = new Object[] {id};

    // Delete
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);
}

/**
 * Edits an existing person
 * @param id the id of the existing person
 * @param firstName the first name of the existing person
 * @param lastName the last name of the existing person
 * @param money the money of the existing person
 */
public void edit(String id, String firstName, String lastName, Double money) {
    logger.debug("Editing existing person");

    // Prepare our SQL statement
    String sql = "update person set first_name = :firstName, " +
            "last_name = :lastName, money = :money where id = :id";

    // Assign values to parameters
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("id", id);
    parameters.put("firstName", firstName);
    parameters.put("lastName", lastName);
    parameters.put("money", money);

    // Edit
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);

}



@Override
public void add(Person person) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void edit(Person person) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




 }
```

I have added this

```
Appilcation context.xml




             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
 For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package-->


<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.a" />



<!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  -->
<mvc:annotation-driven /> 

<import resource="jdbc-context.xml" />
```

Now I am not getting datasource bean error but only the error not find autowire bean.
When I tried to add 
com.app.service.PersonService
com.app.r.Personrepo.  in application context.xml

It gives me http not found error uri

Comment: You have no `Personrepo` implementation.

Comment: I have tried that but still getting the same error.

Comment: Tried what? You haven't shown us a class that implements `Personrepo` that is annotated with `@Repository`.

Comment: Please view the updated PersonService class at the bottom.thanks

Comment: Are you still getting the same exact error?

Comment: Yes " Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.app.r.Personrepo com.app.a.HomeController.personRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined"

Comment: Did you read the exception?  You have no bean named 'dataSource' in your ApplicationContext, but you are attempting to inject one into your `PersonService` class.

Comment: @amzi That is a different exception. As nicholas said, you have not defined a `dataSource` bean

Comment: yes but is this related with the autowiring error of Personrepo or it is seperate.

Comment: I have added applicationcontext.xml now I am not getting datasoruce bean error but only autowire error.In application context I only scan the controller package.When I was trying to add service and repo class it was giving uril not found in dispatcher servlet.ERROR is "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.app.r.Personrepo com.app

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a chameleon question.

Answer (score 1):

Spent much of my time with this! My bad! Later found that the class on which I declared the annotation `Service` or `Component` was of type abstract. Had enabled debug logs on Springframework but no hint was received. Please check if the class if of abstract type. If then, the basic rule applied, can't instantiate an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem. I resolved this after properly naming the the package name in the following code `<context:component-scan base-package="com.mysweethome"></context:component-scan>`

Answer (score 0):

if you've tried all the suggestions but still not work, then here's a way that last to do is to delete the project files in server ,for example i'm using tomcat, then go into the `webapps`dir and `work`dir, delete the corresponding project file. Be cautious when deleting.

i solved the same issue by this, so i'm considering its cause by the project cache even though cleared the `project`and`server`in the IDE.Wish it can help :)